# Matlab write image with floating point values?

Tags: image, matlab, floating-point, tiff

I have a `.tif` image where each pixel value (single channel) is floating point. Is there anyway to read it with matlab (`imread`) do some operation and write it back in floating point ?

If i do `imwrite(I,'img.tif')` it gets converted to 8 bit single channel (0...255)

I only found this sample on mathworks:

```
info = imfinfo(filename); 
t = Tiff(filename, 'w'); 
tagstruct.ImageLength = size(timg, 1); 
tagstruct.ImageWidth = size(timg, 2); 
tagstruct.Compression = Tiff.Compression.None; 
tagstruct.SampleFormat = Tiff.SampleFormat.IEEEFP; 
tagstruct.Photometric = Tiff.Photometric.MinIsBlack; 
tagstruct.BitsPerSample = info.BitsPerSample; % 32; 
tagstruct.SamplesPerPixel = info.SamplesPerPixel; % 1; 
tagstruct.PlanarConfiguration = Tiff.PlanarConfiguration.Chunky; 
t.setTag(tagstruct); 
t.write(timg); 
t.close();
```

Imfinfo:

```
   info = 

                 Filename: [1x110 char]
              FileModDate: '04-dic-2012 12:02:07'
                 FileSize: 45720930
                   Format: 'tif'
            FormatVersion: []
                    Width: 2724
                   Height: 4193
                 BitDepth: 32
                ColorType: 'grayscale'
          FormatSignature: [73 73 42 0]
                ByteOrder: 'little-endian'
           NewSubFileType: 0
            BitsPerSample: 32
              Compression: 'Uncompressed'
PhotometricInterpretation: 'BlackIsZero'
             StripOffsets: [4193x1 double]
          SamplesPerPixel: 1
             RowsPerStrip: 1
          StripByteCounts: [4193x1 double]
              XResolution: 100
              YResolution: 100
           ResolutionUnit: 'None'
                 Colormap: []
      PlanarConfiguration: 'Chunky'
                TileWidth: []
               TileLength: []
              TileOffsets: []
           TileByteCounts: []
              Orientation: 1
                FillOrder: 1
         GrayResponseUnit: 0.0100
           MaxSampleValue: 4.2950e+09
           MinSampleValue: 0
             Thresholding: 1
                   Offset: 45720696
             SampleFormat: 'IEEE floating point'
       ModelPixelScaleTag: [3x1 double]
         ModelTiepointTag: [6x1 double]
       GeoKeyDirectoryTag: [52x1 double]
       GeoDoubleParamsTag: [3x1 double]
```

Comment: Can you output `imfinfo(filename)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If what you want to do is read a .tif that contains floats, manipulated it, and write it out again, your code example should work well. Just add in the file read, and the image manipulation, and it should work great.

```
img = imread(in_filename)
timg = 2*timg;
info = imfinfo(in_filename); 

t = Tiff(out_filename, 'w'); 
tagstruct.ImageLength = size(timg, 1); 
tagstruct.ImageWidth = size(timg, 2); 
tagstruct.Compression = Tiff.Compression.None; 
tagstruct.SampleFormat = Tiff.SampleFormat.IEEEFP; 
tagstruct.Photometric = Tiff.Photometric.MinIsBlack; 
tagstruct.BitsPerSample = info.BitsPerSample; % 32; 
tagstruct.SamplesPerPixel = info.SamplesPerPixel; % 1; 
tagstruct.PlanarConfiguration = Tiff.PlanarConfiguration.Chunky; 
t.setTag(tagstruct); 
t.write(timg); 
t.close();
```

Comment: I havent' treid that snippet yet... I asked because I tought there could be a simpler method

Comment: What If I can't know if the input image is in floating point or 0...255 ? Because if it's in 0...255 I need to do an im2double() while if it's floating point i dont' need to do im2double... right? How can i check that

Comment: @Perason: I have added imfinfo in the quesitons

Comment: Anyway this snippet is working good. The problem is I can't know which is the input image stats. It can be 0...255 or floating point

Comment: If you want to convert to floating point, just set the BitsPerPixel to 32, and you should be fine.

Comment: @person: isn't the `Tiff.SampleFormat.IEEEFP;` that sets floating point ?

Comment: In any case, just make sure the format matches what your floating point tiff shows.

Comment: I believe i need some sort of normalization.. because I can't know which is the input format of my input image... Before doing anything I believe I should open my input image.. convert it to floating point with best precision (32 or 64) and then reload it and apply my trasformation.... And at that point write it back in floating point with my precision